# Memecached setup problems

Tags: cache

I have recently moved my site to EE5 and I am trying to setup memcached caching. My host has setup memcache and the php extension and its listed in php info.
My hosts has given me these details

```
 array(
'host' => '/tmp/memcached.sock',
'port' => 11211,
'weight' => 1,
)
```

and I  have added them to the config file like this

```
$config['memcached'] = array(
  array(
    'host' => 'tmp/memcached.sock',
    'port' => 11211,
    'weight' => 1,
  )
);
```

However, when I select 'Memcached' as my caching driver, EE displays the error message "Cannot connect to Memcached, using File driver instead".

I also saw in the EE docs that you add the server ip or local host to the host section but that didnt work either 
[memecached config overrides](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#memcached)

What is the correct syntax for my config file to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

you have missed **/** before *tmp* folder in your config. So config will be like this:

```
$config['memcached'] = array(
  array(
    'host' => '/tmp/memcached.sock',
    'port' => '0',
    'weight' => 1,
  )
);
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that but that is not the answer as its still not working

Comment: do you know what ext your server is using - memcached or memcache?

Comment: its using memcached